# Directional derivatives of a function with respect to different directions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is it true that for the directional derivatives of a function u in $R^{n}$ the following formula holds 
$ \partial u /\partial \nu = \partial u /\partial \xi \,\cos \alpha$ where $ \alpha $ is the angle formed between the directions $ \xi, \,  \nu $. If yes, can you suggest a quick proof of this formula?

Thanks.

Comment: If we have $u:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow R$, where $n>2$, then what exactly do we mean by the angle between $\xi$ and $\nu$?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think this is true?

Let $f(x,y)=xy$, $v=(1,0)$, $\xi=(0,1)$, then, one has:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x,y)=y,\frac{\partial f}{\partial\xi}(x,y)=x,\cos(\alpha)=0.$$

If you want to keep it abstract, notice that if your formula holds true, then:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\xi}$$
for all $f$, $v$ and $\xi$, which is not to be excepted. Indeed, your formula implies:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\leqslant\frac{\partial f}{\partial\xi}.$$

Comment: You are right. Can we say that a similar formula holds when you replace $\cos \alpha$ by an expression Q(\alpha) which depends on $\alpha$ in a more complex way. However can we say that Q(\alpha)  do not depend on the point $x\in R^{n}$ where ∂u/∂ν=∂u/∂ξ Q(\alpha)  is computed at? I know that it is a different question.

Comment: I do not know the answer for sure but I am convinced that such a map does not exist. The directional derivative quantifies how the function change in the given direction.

Comment: Yes, but the properties of the gradient of function $u$ at that point remains the same. At the end the directions on the sphere are changing.   Any direction in $\R^{n}$ can be obtained by special orthogonal matrices, whose diagonalization is pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

We have $${\partial u\over\partial\nu}=\nabla u\cdot\nu=\|\nabla u\|\cos\theta_\nu \\ {\partial u\over\partial\xi}=\nabla u\cdot\xi=\|\nabla u\|\cos\theta_\xi$$ and $\alpha=\theta_\nu-\theta_\xi$. Your equation then becomes $$\|\nabla u\|\cos\theta_\nu=\|\nabla u\|\cos\theta_\xi\cos(\theta_\nu-\theta_\xi)$$ or $$\cos\theta_\nu=\cos\theta_\xi\cos(\theta_\nu-\theta_\xi),$$ which is not true in general.

Comment: You are right. Can we say that a similar formula holds when you replace cosα by an expression Q(\alpha) which depends on α in a more complex way. However can we say that Q(\alpha) do not depend on the point x∈Rn where ∂u/∂ν=∂u/∂ξ Q(\alpha) is computed at? I know that it is a different question.

Comment: @FrancescoCiardiello The derivative of a differentiable function $u$ in the direction of the unit vector $\xi$ is equal to the length of the projection of $\nabla u$ onto $\xi$. Any other relationship among directional derivatives is entirely an artifact of $u$. If $u$ is not differentiable at a point, then all bets are off when it comes to directional derivatives there.